# Using Micrososft Azure Backup for backing up VHDs

Tags: backup, azure, vhd

is it possible to backup my VHD files with Microsoft Azure Backup?
Does it upload only the file differences or does it upload the complete file every time?
I dont want to upload the complete file every day so a full upload is not an option every time because of limited bandwith

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can backup your VHD files with Azure backup, you can use "Data Protection Manager" with Azure agent for this purpose.

Once the backup is configured correctly, your backup service will take an "Express Full Backup" from the files, and then start taking changes as snapshots, this will minimize the backup time and storage needs.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757970.aspx